# RecyclerView list ended listener

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I have RecyclerView and I wish to download more data when my list ended.
In ListFragment I had this code:

```
public void onScroll(AbsListView absListView, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    boolean loadMore = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount;
    if (loadMore && !getLoaderManager().hasRunningLoaders()) {
        getLoaderManager().restartLoader(LOADER_ID);
    }
}
```

What should I use with RecyclerView to get the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Adapter class I wrote this code

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    Item item = mItems.get(position);
    viewHolder.Text.setText(item.getTitle());

    if (position == mItems.size() - 1) {
        mListener.onListEnded();
    }
}
```